# Extract value in Web scraping with Python Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, css, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

How can I extract the values '**1.00 TK = 779.8**' from the HTML code below?

I tried below code but it din't work;

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = requests.get(<url>).text

##here is the html page content'''<span _ngcontent-his-c101="" id="driveValue" class="ng-binding ng-scope"> 1.00 TK = 779.8<span _ngcontent-his-c101="">Disk Drive Value</span>(DDV) </span>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
print(soup.find(id='driveValue').find_next(text=True).strip())
```

ERROR:

```
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_next'
```

Comment: I tried extracting the value using id="driveValue" and it results none

Answer (score 0):

Use `find_next()`, which returns the first match:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<span _ngcontent-his-c101="" id="driveValue" class="ng-binding ng-scope"> 1.00 TK = 779.8<span _ngcontent-his-c101="">Disk Drive Value</span>(DDV) </span>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
print(soup.find(id='driveValue').find_next(text=True).strip())
```

Output:

```
1.00 TK = 779.8
```

**Edit:** Use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

URL = "https://www.westernunion.com/us/en/web/send-money/start?SrcCode=12345&ReceiveCountry=IN&SendAmount=100&ISOCurrency=CNY&FundsOut=BA&FundsIn=CreditCard"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(URL)
sleep(10)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")

price = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span.ng-binding.ng-scope").text
print(price)

driver.quit()
```

Output:

```
1.00 USD = 73.9375 Indian Rupee (INR)
```

Comment: getting an error AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_next'

Comment: @itgeek The page is probably loaded dynamically. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64143412/12349734) using `selenium` to scrape a dynamic page.

Comment: i tried this as well,   print(soup.find('span',id="driveValue")) and it prints "None"

Comment: your solutions helps when i want to extract a value from a string "html = '''<span _ngcontent-his-c101="" id="driveValue" class="ng-binding ng-scope"> 1.00 TK = 779.8<span _ngcontent-his-c101="">Disk Drive Value</span>(DDV) </span>'''
"

Comment: Here's i don't have a string. I posted html snippet from page content. I'm getting the below error when I execute your solution for my requirement; AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_next'

Comment: @itgeek please share the URL

Comment: URL: https://www.westernunion.com/us/en/web/send-money/start?SrcCode=12345&ReceiveCountry=IN&SendAmount=100&ISOCurrency=CNY&FundsOut=BA&FundsIn=CreditCard

Comment: and id="smoExchangeRate". and the value that needs to be extracted is "73.9375"

Comment: I'm new to web scrapping, just started learning. :-)

Comment: thanks I kind of knew possibilities using selenium. I was wondering if I can do without selenium.

Answer (score -2):

Hope its help.

```
from lxml import etree
txt = '''<span _ngcontent-his-c101="" id="driveValue" class="ng-binding ng-scope"> 1.00 TK = 779.8<span _ngcontent-his-c101="">Disk Drive Value</span>(DDV) </span>'''

root = etree.fromstring(txt)
for td in root.xpath('//span[contains(@class, "ng-binding ng-scope")]'):
    print(td.text)
```

print output

```
1.00 TK = 779.8
```

Comment: Thanks Samsul .. Is there any way to extract using "ID" ?

Comment: Why use XML parsing when the OP has the BeautifulSoup  tag?

Comment: Isn't it possible using beautifulSoap ?

Comment: yes, it is possible to extract using id. I use XML parsing because  easy-to-use library for processing XML and HTML in the Python.

Comment: It works fine when i just use string but here i need to read the content of the page, and extract the value .

Comment: page = requests.get(<url>)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    root = etree.fromstring(soup)
    print(root)
    for td in root.xpath('//span[contains(@class, "ng-binding ng-scope")]'):
        print(td.text)

Comment: error:     root = etree.fromstring(soup)
  File "src/lxml/etree.pyx", line 3237, in lxml.etree.fromstring
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1895, in lxml.etree._parseMemoryDocument
ValueError: can only parse strings

Comment: It may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36449369/python-xpath-lxml-etree-xpathevalerror-invalid-predicate